# Getting undefined array after .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to insert the first value in a array in a useState but it comes as undefined. I know that the array contains the value that.

```
    let {id} = useParams();
    const [currentJacuzzi, setCurrentJacuzzi] = useState();
    const {jacuzzis} = useContext(JacuzziContext);
    const [mappedJacuzzis, setMappedJacuzzis] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const tempArr = jacuzzis.filter(jacuzzi => jacuzzi.brand === id);
        const mapped = tempArr.map((obj) => (
            {
                name: obj.name,
                about: obj.aboutProduct,
                image: obj.images[0].image
            }
        ));
        setMappedJacuzzis(mapped); 
        setCurrentJacuzzi(mappedJacuzzis[0]); //-- mappedJacuzzis contains an array with objects at this point. But 
    }, [jacuzzis]);
```

mappedJacuzzis contains a array with 3 objects, I wish to get a new value containing only the first object in this array. currentJacuzzi should contain the first value, but is undefined.

```
   <Row className="justify-content-center">
     <h1>{currentJacuzzi.name}</h1>
   </Row>
   <Row className="justify-content-center mr-5 ml-5">
     <p>{currentJacuzzi.about}</p>
   </Row>
```

Comment: probaly because tempArr is empty? Can check if tempArr has the filtered options as expected

Comment: tempArr is not empty, mappedJacuzzis is not empty and contains what is expected. Its when I try to assign the first value in mappedJacuzzis array it becomes undefined. @thenaamsake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a condition before you add the currentJacuzzi
like this, because in the first render, it's value is undefined

````
import "./styles.css";
const dummyData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "something one"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'something two'
  }
]
export default function App() {
  const [mappedJagg, setMappedJagg] = useState([])
  const [currentJagg, setCurrentJagg] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = dummyData.filter(fi => fi.id === 1)
    const mapped = filtered.map(f => ({
      id: f.id,
      text: f.text
    }))
    setMappedJagg(mapped)
    setCurrentJagg(mapped[0])
  }, [])

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log(currentJagg.text)
  // }, [currentJagg])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{currentJagg && currentJagg.text}</h1> // add a condition like this
    </div>
  );
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use `setCurrentJacuzzi(mapped[0]);` if mappedJacuzzis is just set with this value? setMappedJacuzzis won't change value of mappedJacuzzis immediately and you haven't even placed mappedJacuzzis in dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem might be that when you are setting `setMappedJacuzzis(mapped)` and using the updated state in the same block which might not be updated yet. you can just use `setCurrentJacuzzi(mapped[0])` if you don't want to do that use a seprate useEffect hook with mappedJacuzzis in the dependency array.

first method

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const tempArr = jacuzzis.filter(jacuzzi => jacuzzi.brand === id);
        const mapped = tempArr.map((obj) => (
            {
                name: obj.name,
                about: obj.aboutProduct,
                image: obj.images[0].image
            }
        ));
        setMappedJacuzzis(mapped); 
        setCurrentJacuzzi(mapped[0]); //-- mappedJacuzzis is a array with objects
    }, [jacuzzis]);
```

second method

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const tempArr = jacuzzis.filter(jacuzzi => jacuzzi.brand === id);
        const mapped = tempArr.map((obj) => (
            {
                name: obj.name,
                about: obj.aboutProduct,
                image: obj.images[0].image
            }
        ));
        setMappedJacuzzis(mapped); 
    }, [jacuzzis]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const currentJacuzzi = mappedJacuzzis[0]
      setCurrentJacuzzi(currentJacuzzi);
    },[mappedJacuzzis]);
```